# fullscreen background video not working on 18:9 mobile devices

Tags: html, css, sass

I implemented a fullscreen background video for this website https://www.yu-performance.at with the code below. It works fine on desktop and also on most mobile devices. Only on mobile devices with the 18:9 format there is white space above and below the video like shown below, but I want the video to also be fullscreen on 18:9 devices. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

The video on 18:9 device with whitespace:
[screenshot mobile 18:9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rjqe.png)

The website has a background video in the first section which is emulated as background size cover, using the following styles:

```
//container div
.banner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    //fullsize background video
    video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        min-width: 1000%;
        min-height: 1000%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        z-index: -100;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1005);
    }
```

Comment: Use `object-fit: cover`.

Comment: @Terry thank you that seems like an even better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the video is 16:9 and on 18:9 mobile devices the video doesn't fill out the entire viewport. So I wrote another media query for only 18:9 devices that forces the video to resize to full-window-height and then the video will automatically cover the entire screen, because the width of the upscaled 16:9 video will be bigger than the screen width.

```
    @media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 9/18) and (orientation: portrait) {
        video {
            min-width: 100% !important;
            min-height: 100% !important;
            width: auto !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.0) !important;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

just use this code in your style.css (line no. 577) code and it will be display on full screen for all screens

```
.banner video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -100; 
}
```

right now you are giving left right position with transform which is useless

Comment: The left and right position and the transform is used for video centering, so it is necessary, also with your code the video would not cover the whole screen

Comment: I have write this code and tested try once you can also use it into media query only for mobile 

if you still have an issue after this code then please write this code and let me see online on you website 
then I can give you better solution 

I still believe that my code is working